# MySQL - Get all data related to foreign key in a single row

Tags: mysql, json

I have two tables, say:

TABLE_A:

```
id | name | student_id
1  | John | 01
2  | Jane | 02
...
```

TABLE_B

```
id | student_id | book_name
1  | 01         | "SQL"
2  | 01         | "Learning SQL"
3  | 01         | "Mastering SQL"
4  | 02         | "SQL engines"
5  | 02         | "SQL and MySQL"
....
```

My question is: how can I get, if it's possible, all data related to student John?
I mean, is there a command that gives me this output after a `select * from ...`:

```
id  |  name  |  student_id  |  book_name
1   |  John  |  01          |  {"SQL","Learning SQL","Mastering SQL"}
2   |  Jane  |  02          |  {"SQL engines","SQL and MySQL"}
```

like there is a `CONCAT()` command on `book_name` column for each book of John and Jane?

I have a php backend that speaks to my db, I can get all John's info in TABLE_A, all data in TABLE_B and then do some magic with array and so on.
But my db is pretty big and I don't want to go this way if not strictly necessary, I was wondering if, maybe with a foreign key like `TABLE_A.student_id`<->`TABLE_B.student_id`, is possible to get what I need.

Thanks!

p.s. I use InnoDB
p.p.s ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is enabled

Comment: Would you be fine with a valid JSON result `["SQL engines","SQL and MySQL"]` instead of `{"SQL engines","SQL and MySQL"}`? What is your MySQL version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [JSON_ARRAYAGG()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_json-arrayagg) to generate a valid JSON array:

```
select a.id, a.name, a.student_id,
  json_arrayagg(b.book_name) as book_names
from TABLE_A a
join TABLE_B b on b.student_id = a.student_id
group by a.id, a.name, a.student_id
```

Result:

```
| id  | name | student_id | book_names                               |
| --- | ---- | ---------- | ---------------------------------------- |
| 1   | John | 01         | ["SQL", "Learning SQL", "Mastering SQL"] |
| 2   | Jane | 02         | ["SQL and MySQL", "SQL engines"]         |
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cR8fhVBzrJuJW33UxQfFmC/0)

You can then use [json_decode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to parse it in PHP.

If you need the result in the same format as in your question, you can try this:

```
select a.id, a.name, a.student_id,
  concat('{', group_concat(json_quote(b.book_name)), '}') as book_names
from TABLE_A a
join TABLE_B b on b.student_id = a.student_id
group by a.id, a.name, a.student_id
```

Result:

```
| id  | name | student_id | book_names                             |
| --- | ---- | ---------- | -------------------------------------- |
| 1   | John | 01         | {"Learning SQL","SQL","Mastering SQL"} |
| 2   | Jane | 02         | {"SQL engines","SQL and MySQL"}        |
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sRq8XB6soMKNES5e19vREr/0)

Both queries require at least MySQL 5.7.

Prior to MySQL 5.7 you would need to add quotes manually:

```
select a.id, a.name, a.student_id,
  concat('{', group_concat('"', b.book_name, '"'), '}') as book_names
from TABLE_A a
join TABLE_B b on b.student_id = a.student_id
group by a.id, a.name, a.student_id
```

But then be sure, that book names don't contain any double quotes.

Comment: Thanks very much, it worked! json_arryagg is exactly what I needed!
I'd like to ask you, what if I need to do a `select TABLE_A.*, json_arrayagg(TABLE_B.book_name) ...`? Because this example was reduced from my real table that contains multiple columns, so I'd like to be able to get all columns and continue to use json_arrayagg for book_name column only, if it's possible. I tried with `select *` but the group by part is not working anymore

Comment: Sorry, maybe I've had some typos in my query and I didn't understand why it was not working. I resolved, many thanks!

Comment: @pippo You can use `select a.* ... group by a.student_id` if `student_id` is `PRIMARY KEY` or `UNIQUE` and `NOT NULL`. I usually group by the primary key. So if `id` is PK, you can use `select a.* ... group by a.id`. That should work in any MySQL version with default settings. If your version doesn't support [*functional dependency detection*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functional-dependence.html) you will need to list all selected columns in the GROUP BY clause. But all those versions (AFAIK including all MariaDB versions) neither support `JSON_ARRAYAGG()`.

Answer (score 2):

Join the tables and group by student. Then use `concat()` and `group_concat()`:

```
select a.id, a.name, a.student_id,
  concat('{', group_concat(b.book_name order by b.id), '}') book_name
from table_a a inner join table_b b
on b.student_id = a.student_id
group by a.id, a.name, a.student_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's called [`group_concat`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html)

```
select name, student_id, group_concat(book_name)
  from table_a
  join table_b using (student_id)
group by student_id
```

[sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9473e3/2)

Comment: there was some initial errors ... but it run fine now

Comment: Warning: this may not run in MySQL if `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` be enabled.

Comment: Sure, but it runs on sql fiddle and it shows all the relevant parts OP is asking for. There are also no indexes on my fiddle and if these tables are million and million of rows it might be inefficient.